# How to get pinterest/peach like module in iOS

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development and was curious as to how something like this is achieved? I really like the overlaying module they have in place here with the comments and boards and was just wondering if anybody could inform me how to achieve something like this? I couldn't find anything like it on SO, YouTube or CococaControls so if somebody could give me the insider on this I would REALLY appreciate it!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try *anything*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved the same by showing a simple modal window.
There are some adjustment you have to do achieve that black overlay.

> 1. Create a view controller change the view color to black with opacity

[image]

This will make your view look a bit transparent.

> 2. Ctrl+Drag from one view controller to another and choose segue kind as "Present modally"

[image]

> 3. Now click on your segue you create and choose presentation as `Over Current Context`

[image]

You can modify the modal view controller the way you wanted and this way you can get the same effect.

Hope this will guide you in correct direction.